# dynamically setting parameter type using IDbDataParameter[] in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have one method which is giving me dataset return. but for that I have to pass all the parameters which my SP
expects for the SQL.

I am creating all the parameter of the SP dynamically. 
So when I try to create the parameter it is giving me null pointer exception.

I have one method which is returning me the `IDbDataParameter[]` I want to add parameter in the `IDbDataParameter[]` array.

I have written this line to add 5 parameters to the array

```
IDbDataParameter[] param = IDbDataParameter(5);

public IDbDataParameter[] CreateParams(WorkEntry workEntry,string CallingPage,string Operation)
{
      IDbDataParameter[] param = new IDbDataParameter(5);

      param[0].DbType = DbType.Int32;
      param[0].Size = 50;
      param[0].ParameterName = "@AutoID";
      param[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

      param[1].DbType = DbType.String;
      param[1].Size = 50;
      param[1].ParameterName = "@OperatorName";
      param[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;

      param[2].DbType = DbType.String;
      param[2].Size = 50;
      param[2].ParameterName = "@Date";
      param[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;

      param[3].DbType = DbType.String;
      param[3].Size = 50;
      param[3].ParameterName = "@StartDate";
      param[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

      param[4].DbType = DbType.String;
      param[4].Size = 50;
      param[4].ParameterName = "@EndDate";
      param[4].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

      return param;
}
```

After this line when it tries to add parameter then it is giving me 
object reference not set to instance of the object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line you are getting error?

Comment: this line param[0].DbType = DbType.Int32;

Comment: Show the code for method `GetParameters(5)`

Comment: sorry i have updated the question now

Comment: I think it should be `IDbDataParameter[] param = new IDbDataParameter(5);` You are missing `new` keyword

Comment: Your `GetParameters(5)` is returning a `NULL`

Comment: yes in my code it is like that only

Comment: You still haven't added `GetParemeters` method code in your question

Comment: i have changed my code and still itts not workin

Comment: @HardikParmar - define: `not working`. Did you try what I suggested in my answer?

Comment: Yes your answer works fine for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
IDbDataParameter[] param = IDbDataParameter(5);
```

looks like* you're creating a new array, however it does not create an instance for every element in the array. On the next line where you do this:

```
param[0].DbType = DbType.Int32;
```

`param[0]` is still null. You need to instantiate it

```
param[0] = new SqlParameter(); // or whatever implementation you're using.
param[0].DbType = DbType.Int32;
....
```

---

* I say "looks like", but it does not look like valid syntax - that should be something like

```
IDbDataParameter[] param = new IDbDataParameter[5];
```

Comment: Yes sir its working perfectly fine. & one more doubt the reason was not creating the object was interface ? coz of interface it was not intialising. & another doubt how we can allowed to create the object for the interface IDbDataParameter[] param = new IDbDataParameter[5];

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not creating the parameter, so your array contains 5 null values. Here is better implementation, replace the SqlParameter the appropriate parameter type for you db provider.

```
  private IDbDataParameter CreateParameter(DbType parameterType, int size, string name, ParameterDirection direction)
  {
    return new SqlParameter
    {
      DbType = parameterType,
      Size = size,
      ParameterName = name,
      Direction = direction
    };
  }

  public IDbDataParameter[] CreateParams(WorkEntry workEntry, string CallingPage, string Operation)
  {
    IDbDataParameter[] param = new[]
    {
      CreateParameter(DbType.Int32, 50, "@AutoID", ParameterDirection.ReturnValue),
      CreateParameter(DbType.String, 50, "@OperatorName", ParameterDirection.InputOutput),
      CreateParameter(DbType.String, 50, "@Date", ParameterDirection.InputOutput),
      CreateParameter(DbType.String, 50, "@StartDate", ParameterDirection.Input),
      CreateParameter(DbType.String, 50, "@EndDate", ParameterDirection.Input),
    };

    return param;
  }
```

Consider using DbProviderFactories class to create the parameter.

Comment: thank you sir it is also working. but i do like this IDbDataParameter[] param = CreateParameter(DbType parameterType, int size, string name, ParameterDirection direction) but in this case i will not have to create sqlparameter object everytime & CreateParameter will return IDbDataParameter[]